# SwiftUI Position Google and Facebook login buttons

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, swift5

I am using Firebase Auth and I have two buttons. One for Google and one for Facebook.
I'm trying to set the height and width via `.frame()` but they are not responding properly. 
Moreover, the Google sign in button wont appear in the middle but on the right of the screen.

I tried to put them inside a `VStack` but still the same thing.

```
VStack(alignment: .center) {
    FacebookLoginButtonView()
        .frame(width: 100, height: 28) // duhet 28 fiks
        .border(Color.red)

    GoogleLoginButtonView()
        .frame(width: 100, height: 28)
        .border(Color.red)

}
```

Any idea how to position them in the center and also maybe to give them the same height?
Setting `.frame(width: 100, height: 28)` for FB every height other than 28 will throw an error.

FacebookLoginButtonView

```
struct FacebookLoginButtonView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var userViewModel: UserViewModel
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(userViewModel: userViewModel)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<FacebookLoginButtonView>) -> FBLoginButton {
        let button = FBLoginButton()
        button.permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
        button.delegate = context.coordinator
        return button
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: FBLoginButton, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<FacebookLoginButtonView>) {
        //
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, LoginButtonDelegate {
        var userViewModel: UserViewModel

        init(userViewModel: UserViewModel) {
            self.userViewModel = userViewModel
        }

        func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) {
            if error != nil {
                // print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if let currentAccessToken = AccessToken.current {
                let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: currentAccessToken.tokenString)
                Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: AuthService(userViewModel: userViewModel).registerHandler)
            }
        }

        func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton) {
            try? Auth.auth().signOut()
        }
    }
}
```

GoogleLoginButtonView

```
struct GoogleLoginButtonView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var userViewModel: UserViewModel
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(userViewModel: userViewModel)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<GoogleLoginButtonView>) -> GIDSignInButton {
        let button = GIDSignInButton()
        button.style = .wide
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = context.coordinator
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
        return button
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: GIDSignInButton, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<GoogleLoginButtonView>) {

    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, GIDSignInDelegate {
        var userViewModel: UserViewModel

        init(userViewModel: UserViewModel) {
            self.userViewModel = userViewModel
        }

        func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
            // ...
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
            let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: AuthService(userViewModel: userViewModel).registerHandler)
        }

        func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
            // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I assume you used UIViewRepresentable to wrap those two buttons. If so, can you post the code for them?

Comment: you are right, check my updated question please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably noticed that your frames are too small and those buttons have rigid size, you can make them bigger or at least for Google button try using any of the [other styles](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/reference/Classes/GIDSignInButton), you are now using `button.style = .wide`.

Another solution is to do not use them, create your own views to replicate each button and call the functions behind the scenes.

Google:

```
struct GoogleAuthButtonView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
            //Any other function here
        }) {
            HStack {
                Image("icon-google").renderingMode(.original)
                    .accessibility(label: Text("Sign in with Google"))
                Spacer()
                Text("Sign in with Google")
                    .foregroundColor(.cGoogleAuthText).bold()
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .cornerRadius(16)
        .background(Color.white)
        .shadow(color: Color.init(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, opacity: 0.06), radius: 8, x: 0, y: 4)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 28)
    }
}
```

Facebook is the same idea but changing the action:

```
Button(action: {
    LoginManager().logIn(permissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: UIHostingController(rootView: self)) { (result, error) in
        //Do stuff here
    }
}) {
    Text("Continue with Facebook")
}
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks for now I will go with the default ones. I increased the width and they are displaying in the middle